# Lamp casting only on its own collection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

Back in the 2.7x days, I seem to recall a feature for "this layer only," leaving lamps and things only affecting the layer they were on.

In 2.8x, of course, layers have been replaced with collections. However, I cannot seem to find a "this collection only" with which to isolate which collections the lamp affects.

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: This was an option that existed only for the Blender Internal render engine. I don't think Eevee has that feature.

Comment: Hm, yes. Is there a way to achieve it in Cycles? I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: You can do something similar by putting them into separate collections and then create several view layers where a specific collection is exclude. In the compositor you can combine the rendered images.